# Error ImproperlyConfigured DetailView Django 1.8

Tags: django, detailsview

How to corrige error?

See my error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at schedule/confirmed/c4e068dc-9e89-4fa5-9a66-cfb5ec6a306b/
ScheduleConfirmed is missing a QuerySet. Define ScheduleConfirmed.model, ScheduleConfirmed.queryset, or override ScheduleConfirmed.get_queryset().
```

And see my views.py

```
# views.py
class ScheduleConfirmed(generic.DetailView):
    modal = Schedule
    template_name = 'schedule-confirmed.html'

    # def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    #     context = super(ScheduleConfirmed, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    #     obj = self.object
    #     return context
```

my urls.py

```
#urls.py
    url(r'^schedule/confirmed/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$', views.ScheduleConfirmed.as_view(), name='schedule_confirmed'),
```

my models.py

```
#models.py
class Schedule(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='schedule_creator')
    # ...
```

Answer (score 4):

You've got a typo in your ScheduleConfirmed class attribute. Just change `modal` to `model` and it should work as expected.